# Android Studio: Is is possible to set default drawable folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable, android-drawable

I am having a rather annoying scenario where I work with a lot of drawable shapes, many of which are slightly changed variants of others. The annoying thing is, when I paste the drawable, it automatically defaults to a random resource folder. See bellow photo. I want it to go directly to the standard drawable folder, not some other density drawable folders without having to manually change the folder every single time.

Is this even possible?

[image]

Comment: The solution to this is using SVG(vector assets) images . 
-------
drawable -> right click -> new -> vector asset -> select (local file SVG,PSD) -> location of image. 
--------
This will adapt to all devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the **View** from **Android** to **Project** if you are copying & pasting multiple images in a row. You can simply paste it to the drawable folder.

[image: Drawable folder]